# Find the value of k, (if any), for which the system below has unique, infinite or no solution.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

The system of equations are:

$\begin{cases}x+y+kz = 1\\x+ky+z=1\\kx+y+z=1\\
\end{cases}$

I am looking to finding values of $k$, for which this system has either no solutions, infinite many solutions or a unique solution (if any).

I've had a look around the web for some help, and know that this question has been asked, but in a way that I have not yet learnt (something to do with determinants I think).

However, I have only been working with reducing the matrix to REF/RREF and thus I'm trying to find rows, such as $( 0 \ 0 \ 0 \mid 2)$ and $( 0 \ 0 \ 0 \mid 0)$ etc to show if we have no solutions or infinite many solutions, for instance.

So far, I've got the following:

$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}1&1&k&1\\1&k&1&1\\k&1&1&1\end{array}\right]$

Then, $R_2$$\mapsto$$R_2-R_1$

$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}1&1&k&1\\0&k-1&1-k&0\\k&1&1&1\end{array}\right]$

Then, $R_2$ $\leftrightarrow$ $R_3$

$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}1&1&k&1\\k&1&1&1\\0&k-1&1-k&0\end{array}\right]$

This is where I got stuck, and I'm not sure how to continue.

Thank you in advance, and I'm sorry if this question has been asked and solved in the same way as presented above.

Cheers.

Comment: This post asks about the same problem: [System of Linear Equations - how many solutions?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/930252/system-of-linear-equations-how-many-solutions/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, there is at least one another post about the same problem: [System of Linear Equations - how many solutions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/930252/system-of-linear-equations-how-many-solutions/)

Let me address your attempt. (I think that as soon as you are satisfied with the feedback you got on your attempt to solve the problem, this post might be closed as a duplicate of some other post asking the same question.)

> $\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}1&1&k&1\\k&1&1&1\\0&k-1&1-k&0\end{array}\right]$
>
> This is where I got stuck, and I'm not sure how to continue.

Now a reasonable step would be to divide the last row by $(k-1)$. But this is only possible if $k-1\ne0$.

So you can:

- Solve the case $k=1$ separately.
- For $k\ne 1$ divide the last row by $(k-1)$ which leads you to a simpler matrix - you should try whether you are able to continue from there.

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}1&1&k&1\\k&1&1&1\\0&1&-1&0\end{array}\right]$$

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Didn't realise that a similar question existed. On a side note, I assume the matrix you wrote, is the one in the quote but the last row divided by (k-1)? If so, should the last row be: $( 0 \ 1 \ -1 \mid 0)$?

Comment: @KidMe Fair enough, I wrote that I am going to divide by $(k-1)$, so I should have done that. (Although dividing by $(1-k)$ would work as well.) I will correct my post.

Comment: Thanks for the simpler matrix: $\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}1&1+k&0&1\\k&2&0&1\\0&1&-1&0\end{array}\right]$ I've managed to get to it from the previous matrix, but still stuck on what to do next to see whether system is consistent/inconsistent for when k is not equal to 1.

(Nb: I've managed to merge the two accounts, thank you for that link!).

Comment: @KidMe Using $R_2 \leftarrow R_2-k\cdot R_1$ you get
$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}1&1+k&0&1\\0&2-k-k^2&0&1-k\\0&1&-1&0\end{array}\right]$. If you notice that $k^2+k-2=(k+2)(k-1)$, you should be able to divide the second row by $(k-1)$. And you will get even simpler matrix, since in the second row you have only one non-zero coefficient.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've done what you said, and got the following:
$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}1& 1+k&0&1\\0&-(K+2)&0 &((1-k)/(k-1))\\0&1&-1&0\end{array}\right]$.

Comment: @KidMe You wanted to write this? $\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}1&1+k&0&1\\ 0&-(k+2)&0&((1-k)/(k-1))\\ 0&1&-1&0\end{array}\right]$. There is a problem with ling strings without spaces in comments, as explained [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5137/too-long-latex-formulae-not-shown-in-comments).

Comment: Since $(1-k)/(k-1)$, you actually have $\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}1&1+k&0&1\\ 0&-(k+2)&0&-1\\ 0&1&-1&0\end{array}\right]$ which leads to $\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}1&1+k&0&1\\ 0&1&0&\frac1{k+2}\\ 0&1&-1&0\end{array}\right]$. So you get $y=\frac1{k+2}$.
You should notice that in this step we divide by $(k+2)$. So the case $k=-2$ must be solved separately.

Comment: @KidMe Now you almost have the solution. But it will be still useful for you to look at solutions posted in other answers to see that there is an easier way to get to this.

Comment: Thank you for that. Still getting used to this way of typing maths! I see how it is probably easier to follow other ways to finding the solutions, but now that we are near the solution, could you explain how we would go about to getting it from your method, and how do we solve the cases when k=-2 (and k=1) once we get to that stage? Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @KidMe Once you have the value of $y$, you can get the value of $x$ from the first equation (which does not contain $z$.) The third row corresponds to the equation $y-z=0$, so you have $y=z$. The remaining two cases are just systems without parameter, just with numbers. So it is a standard problem. (And I think they are solved in some of the other answers.)

Comment: What would happen if the system was x+y+kz=, x+ky+z=1, kx+y+z=-2? Would the values of k for which the solution is unique be the same?

Comment: @416256 Your system is missing the RHS in the first equation. However, independently of the RHS, we have that system has exactly one solution if and only if the determinant is non-zero. The determinant is $(k+2)(k-1)^2$. So for $k\ne1,-2$ the system has exactly one solution. For $k=-2$ amd for $k=1$ it has either no solution or infinitely many solutions, this depends on what the RHS look like.

Answer (score 2):

I would restart from:
$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}1&1&k&1\\0&k-1&1-k&0\\k&1&1&1\end{array}\right]$$
then $\,R_3\leftarrow R_3-kR_1$:
$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}1&1&k&1\\0&k-1&1-k&0\\0&1-k&1-k^2&1-k\end{array}\right]$$
$R_3\leftarrow R_3+R_2$:
$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}1&1&k&1\\0&k-1&1-k&0\\0&0&(1-k)(2+k)&1-k\end{array}\right]\tag{1}$$
**Suppose for now** $\boldsymbol {k\neq 1,-2}.$
$R_2\leftarrow \frac{1}{k-1}R_2$:
$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}1&1&k&1\\0&1&-1&0\\0&0&(1-k)(2+k)&1-k\end{array}\right]$$
then  $\,R_2\leftarrow R_2+\frac1{(1-k)(2+k)}R_3$ and $\,R_1\leftarrow R_1-\frac k{(1-k)(2+k)}R_3$:
$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}1&1&0&\dfrac2{2+k}\\0&1&0&\dfrac1{2+k}\\0&0&(1-k)(2+k)&1-k\end{array}\right]$$
and finally $\,R_1\leftarrow R_1-R_2$, $\,R_3\leftarrow \frac1{(1-k)(2+k)}R_3$

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}1&0&0&\dfrac1{2+k}\\0&1&0&\dfrac1{2+k}\\0&0&1&\dfrac1{2+k}\end{array}\right]$$
The solution is $\enspace x=y=z=\dfrac1{2+k}$.

**If $\boldsymbol{k=1}$**: the matrix (1) becomes
$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}1&1&1&1\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{array}\right]$$
so the solutions consists in the plane $\,x+y+z=1$.

**If $\boldsymbol{k=-2}$**: the matrix becomes:
$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}1&1&-2&1\\0&1&-1&0\\0&0&0&-1\end{array}\right]$$
and the last row shows there's no solution.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I think your solution is quite nice, but I'll see how I get on with @Martin way first. Cheers.

Comment: Hey there again! I've been looking back at your solution, and I get everything, except for the last matrix. From matrix (1), I obtained, the following, when $k$=-2:

$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}1&1&-2&1\\0&-3&3&0\\0&0&0&3\end{array}\right]$

then $R_2$ $\leftarrow$ -(1/3)$R_2$
and $R_3$ $\leftarrow$ (1/3)$R_3$:

$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}1&1&-22&1\\0&1&-1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{array}\right]$


Which is not what you had obtained. Have I gone wrong somewhere? @Martin

Comment: @KidMe: I don't undeerstand how you obtain $22$.  Mine should have $-2$, not 2$, it's true. This cannot change the conclusion, however.

Comment: Sorry, yes that is a typo. It is meant to say -2.

Also could I confirm that for when k is not 1 or -2, then we have a unique solution?

Comment: Pivot's algorithm, which I deployed gives the solution. And, yes, for theoretical reasons, if $k\neq 1,-2$, the matrix is invertible, i.e. is the matrix of an isomorphism.

Comment: I haven't got as far as invertible/isomorphism matrix studies, but thanks for your all your effort in responding to my question!

Comment: It's a simple notion: it means it's the matrix of a (linear) bijection.

Comment: @KidMe I see you have tried to ping me in one of the comments here. You will find more details about comment replies [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/comment-replies/info). But one important thing is that your ping will only reach people who participated in the particular comment thread. (So your ping did not reach me. And there are some other details, see *Who can be notified?* section [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work/43020#43020).)